# how to rotate an image in clockwise and counterclockwise in android?

Tags: android

I'd like to know how to rotate an image in clockwise and counterclockwise with onTouch() event in android. And how to find out through onTouchListener either it is clockwise or counterclockwise rotation? Thanks

Comment: Use rotate animation, there are a lot of good examples out there... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html

Comment: Thanks, But I want to know the way which rotate an image in clockwise and counterclockwise with onTouch() event in android

Answer (score 0):

Basically you may put your image inside your own class, that extends View  and implements OnClickListener like this:

```
public class CustomImageView extends View implements OnClickListener{
    ...
}
```

Override the onDraw method inside your CustomImageView class. The rotation might be implemented inside onDraw by rotating the canvas object.

Third, implement onClick in order to get click events and do the rotation based on your needs.

A basic layout may look like:

```
public class CustomImageView extends View implements OnClickListener{

     public void onClick (View v){

        // process click here

        // invalidate after click processing in order to redraw
        this.invalidate();
    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // draw your image here, might be bitmap or other stuff

        // rotate canvas now, your logic on clockwise or 
        //  counterclockwise rotation goes here
        canvas.rotate(-90.0f, centerx, centery);

    }        

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I can use Matrix class to rotate image in clockwise and counterclockwise. But  I want to rotate image in clockwise and counterclockwise with onTouch() event.

Comment: It is the same structure as with onClick. Just redraw after processing the touch or the click.

What is your rotation logic? Rotate clockwise on 1st touch and rotate counterclockwise on 2nd touch and so on? You might need a touch counter variable, which counts up, so you know in onDraw in what rotation state the image should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this function to get your rotation from the x and y values from the MotionEvent object.
There I still need to find the direction from the additional calculation from the given vector x and vector y.

```
  private int calculateAngle(float GETX, float GETY) {
    int direction = 1;

    double tx = (int) GETX - object_center.x;
    double ty = (int) GETY - object_center.y;
    double angleInDegrees = Math.atan2(ty, tx) * 180 / Math.PI;
    int area = 0;
    int ACTUAL_ANGLE = 270;

    if (angleInDegrees < 0 && angleInDegrees < -90) {
        // Need to add
        // 270+angle degrees
        // =================
        ACTUAL_ANGLE += (int) (180 + angleInDegrees) * direction;
    } else if (angleInDegrees < 0 && angleInDegrees > -90) {
        // Need to add
        //  90+angle degrees
        // =================
        ACTUAL_ANGLE = (int) (90 + angleInDegrees);
    } else if (angleInDegrees > 0)
        ACTUAL_ANGLE = 90 + (int) angleInDegrees;
    return ACTUAL_ANGLE;
}
```